# what is the correct way to use toolbar on android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, toolbar

I'm trying to set actionbar on my Android Studio project. While debugging, Android Studio doesn't show any error but when I run my app, it stops at this line. Please suggest me the perfect way of working with toolbar on Android Studio.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Edit:
The aforementioned code is from my Activity class file. And here is the extract from my XML file

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: why not using toolbar via xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to use android toolbar> Use toolbar in XML file :

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24_white"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/back_button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tag1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/create_a_push_notification"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backButton"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is the toolbar you can access any component via id. The toolbar will look like this:
[image: Toolbar]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry, for I missed to mention my XML file code on my question. Please review my question again, where I've added extract from my XML file and suggest me my mistakes. Thank you again.